# Match values in another dataframe with two conditions - row and column

Tags: r, conditional-statements, match, calculated-columns

I have these two dataframes which I would like to return the values from the column "price" on the dataframe B to the dataframe A based on the contract number and the component for each column (FE02, FE03, CE64, FE27, etc) as conditions. Can anyone help me with this issue?

Dataframe A:
[image]

Dataframe B:
[image]

Thanks!

I'm expecting to match the values from the column "price" on the second dataframe with the components and contracts on the first dataframe.

Comment: left_join(dfa, dfb, by = "contract")

Comment: I believe you need to first pivot the dataframe A into long format so that you can follow the merge approach that @GuedesBF has suggested, but with a join on both `contract` and `component`.  If absolutely necessay, you could then pivot the resulting join back to wide format.

Comment: Yes, langtang is right, pivot_wider(dfb.... then join

Comment: B has probably quite a few more components and contracts than A. I'd say subset B, pivot wider and semi join by A. To take the guesswork out of this, please add some data samples like was recommended  in comments of your [previous identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76309748/r-studio-match-the-values-with-two-conditions-in-another-dataframe). To save this re-post from closing, please at least take a moment to craft a sample of your expected output and replace (or complement) your screenshots swith data that others can actually use to help you, i.e. output from `dput()`

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

left_join(
  pivot_longer(dfa, -contract, names_to="component") %>% select(-value),
  dfb,
  by=c("contract", "component")
)
```